# Recover deleted file PyCharm

Tags: python, database, pycharm

I'm working on a password manager using python in the PyCharm IDE. I am working with a database to store the passwords, which makes a .db file in the project folder. Then i wanted to clear that file as i wanted a clear db to work with. So i deleted the .db file from my folder, thinking it would create a new file and work fine. However, it did not.

I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/evault/main.py", line 246, in <module>
    open_vault()
  File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/evault/main.py", line 235, in open_vault
    Label(vault, text=(array[i][1]), font=("Helvetica", 12)).place(x=400, y=400)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried reverting changes with local history, but that wouldn't work for me either (or i just didn't understand)

[EDIT] Does it maybe have something to do with a new, so empty, database being created and then trying to display the contents of that database but failing as there are none? The deleted database file by me had contents, which did display. Might also be completely wrong, idk.

If it would help, this is my whole project code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice
import array
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import pyperclip as pc
from functools import partial

# Database
with sqlite3.connect("vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

service = None
username = None
password = None

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vault (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    service TEXT NOT NULL, 
    username TEXT NOT NULL, 
    password TEXT NOT NULL);
    """)


def hash_password(pw):
    hash = hashlib.md5(pw)
    hash = hash.hexdigest()

    return hash


def validate_login():
    # getting form data
    uname = username_log.get()
    pwd = master_key.get()
    # applying empty validation
    if uname == '' or pwd == '':
        message.set("Please fill in all the fields")
    else:
        if uname == "Laurens" and pwd == "password":
            login_screen.destroy()
            open_vault()
        else:
            message.set("Wrong username or password")


def generate_password():
    len = 12

    digits = '0123456789'
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmn' \
            'opqrstuvwxyz'
    up = chars.upper()
    special = '_!$%&?'
    all = digits + chars + up + special
    password = ''.join(
        choice(all) for i in range(len)
    )


    # print out password
    print(password)
    save = messagebox.askyesnocancel("Generated password", f"Your generated safe password is: \n \n {password}  "
                                                           f"\n \n Click yes to copy to clipboard"
                                                           f"\n and click no to generate a new password.")
    if save:
        # 'Yes' > copy to clipboard
        pc.copy(password)
    elif not save and save is not None:
        # 'No' > generate new password
        generate_password()
    else:
        # 'Cancel'
        pass


def save_credentials():
    service_input = service.get()
    username_input = username.get()
    password_input = password.get()

    insert_fields = ("""INSERT INTO vault(service, username, password)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?)
    """)

    cursor.execute(insert_fields, (service_input, username_input, password_input))
    db.commit()
    print(db)

    open_vault()


def remove_credentials(input):
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
    db.commit()

    open_vault()


def register_credentials():
    global service
    global username
    global password

    vault.destroy()

    register_screen = Tk()
    register_screen.resizable(False, False)
    register_screen.title("Login")
    register_screen.geometry("350x500")
    register_screen.configure(bg='#212121')

    service = StringVar()
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    # Service Label
    Label(register_screen, text="Name of service: ", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.5, y=100, anchor=CENTER)

    # Service textbox
    Entry(register_screen, textvariable=service).place(width=180, height=30, relx=0.5, y=140, anchor=CENTER)

    # Username Label
    Label(register_screen, text="Username: ", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.5, y=200, anchor=CENTER)

    # Username textbox
    Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username).place(width=180, height=30, relx=0.5, y=240, anchor=CENTER)

    # Password Label
    Label(register_screen, text="Password: ", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.5, y=300, anchor=CENTER)

    # Password textbox
    Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password).place(width=180, height=30, relx=0.5, y=340, anchor=CENTER)

    # Generate password button
    Button(register_screen, text="Generate safe password", bg='#ABABAB', fg='#000000', command=generate_password).place(
        width=140, height=30, relx=0.5, y=400, anchor=CENTER)

    # Save credentials button
    Button(register_screen, text="Save credentials", bg='#673AB7', fg='#FFFFFF', command=save_credentials).place(
        width=150, height=40, relx=0.5, y=460, anchor=CENTER)

    register_screen.mainloop()


def login_screen():
    global login_screen
    global message
    global username_log
    global master_key

    login_screen = Tk()
    login_screen.resizable(False, False)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x210")
    login_screen.configure(bg='#212121')

    # declaring variable
    username_log = StringVar()
    master_key = StringVar()
    message = StringVar()

    # Creating layout of login form
    Label(login_screen, width="300", text="Please enter username and master key", bg="#673AB7", fg="#FFFFFF").pack()

    # Username Label
    Label(login_screen, text="Username: ", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(x=20, y=40)

    # Username textbox
    Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_log).place(x=90, y=42)

    # Password Label
    Label(login_screen, text="Master key: ", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(x=20, y=80)

    # Password textbox
    Entry(login_screen, textvariable=master_key, show="*").place(x=90, y=82)

    # Label for displaying login status[success/failed]
    Label(login_screen, text="", textvariable=message, bg='#212121', fg='#ff0000').place(relx=0.5, y=125, anchor=CENTER)

    # Login button
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, bg='#673AB7', fg='#FFFFFF', command=validate_login).place(
        x=110, y=150)

    login_screen.mainloop()


def open_vault():
    global vault
    vault = Tk()
    vault.resizable(False, False)
    vault.title("Evault")
    vault.geometry("750x500")
    vault.configure(bg='#212121')

    Label(vault, text="Service", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.2, y=75)

    Label(vault, text="Username", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.45, y=75)

    Label(vault, text="Password", bg='#212121', fg='#ABABAB').place(relx=0.7, y=75)

    Button(vault, text="Register new credentials", bg='#673AB7', fg='#FFFFFF', command=register_credentials).place(
        width=150, height=40, relx=0.5, y=450, anchor=CENTER)

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
    if cursor.fetchall() != None:
        i = 0
        while True:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
            array = cursor.fetchall()

            Label(vault, text=(array[i][1]), font=("Helvetica", 12)).place(x=400, y=400)

            i += 1

            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
            if len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i:
                break

    vault.mainloop()


open_vault()
```

Comment: why do you import array despite never using it (and shadowing the name later?)

Comment: yeah there's more things that are still wrong in the code, i'm still working on it. However, this problem only just came after i deleted the file (the database appeared on the TK screen before) . I use the array variable in the code later but you're right, i don't use the array module, must have been old code from another time i still have to remove.  (i have updated my question btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown by this:

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
if cursor.fetchall() != None:
    i = 0
    while True:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
        array = cursor.fetchall()
        Label(vault, text=(array[i][1]), font=("Helvetica", 12)).place(x=400, y=400)
        i += 1
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vault')
        if len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i:
            break
```

I confess I don't understand what this code is supposed to do.  Why does it repeatedly execute the same query?  You *probably* want something like this:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
START_HEIGHT=400
LINE_HEIGHT=50
for i, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    line_pos = START_HEIGHT + i * LINE_HEIGHT
    Label(vault, text=row[1]).place(x=400,y=line_pos)
```

i.e. just iterate over the rows returned by the cursor directly.

If that is still throwing an error, you need to do some debugging: print what `cursor.fetchall()` actually returns.  (Specifically, print `list(cursor.fetchall())` in case it's an iterator.)

Comment: This works great, thanks for your suggestion! However, i still have a question. Each entry into the database represents one set of credentials. This means that by having for instance Label(vault, text=row[1]).place(x=400,y=250) for the service and Label(vault, text=row[2]).place(x=400,y=300) and Label(vault, text=row[3]).place(x=400,y=350) i can display one entry. But i want to display more entries , the second set of entered credentials simply gets pasted on top of the first set of credentials. Do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: yes: update the position as you loop.  See updated answer (coming in a mo).  Feel free to accept the answer btw if this solves it.

Comment: feel like a total noob seeing the answer haha, should've know this. Anyway, thanks for the help!